# How to find out the screen number from qml code?

Tags: qt, qml

I need to find out whether the popup is visible on the screen. In Qt, I would call
`qApp->desktop()->screenNumber(this)`
within the widget class function.

This code returns -1 when there is no screen number because the given widget is not visible on any screen. I need to find out when this case scenario happens to show the widget on default position on primary screen (when the given screen is not available).

I have no idea how to find out the current screen number in QML code or other way that the pop up is not visible.

Comment: Does the QML `Window`'s `screen` property give you the info you want?

Comment: I investigated the screen property, but I did not found anything useful.

Comment: I'm also stuck in getting the screenumber from Qscreen object. Any hint would be appreciated. I'm very new at QT.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by creating a subclass from QQuickWindow, setting the appropriate flags

---

```
setFlags(Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint | Qt::Popup );
```

---

and creating a function which can be called to find out whether the popup is visible based on the pixel coordinates of the popup

```
bool BlinkReminderWindow::existPointOnScreen(int x, int y)
{
    return QGuiApplication::screenAt(QPoint(x,y))!=nullptr;
}
```